# Twitter API get account with warning "This account is temporarily restricted"

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twython

I am trying to find out users showing the warning **"This account is temporarily restricted"**. I tried to use Twitter API (Tweepy) to extract out the user details but there are no such fields showing whether this warning is enabled or not.

```
result = api.get_user(user_id=<user_id>)
```

An example of one such user is present in this [link](https://twitter.com/jamamccoy1409)

Comment: That is not available in the Twitter API, so you will not be able to succeed by looking into the profile like this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to do it by web scraping the Twitter timeline and looking for the <h2> tags which contained the required information.

Comment: Unfortunately scraping by the web is against Twitters terms of service so I do not recommend you do that as a regular piece of code or your IP may become blocked.